# Passar como argumento o objeto

Tags: java

Existe o método +fazUmaCompra na classe Cliente que calcula o desconto e os pontos do cliente, e no final do método, deveria ser instanciado um objeto do tipo Compra, mas não consigo instanciar o objeto compra.

Atributos e Construtor da classe "Compra":

```
public class Compra{
    private String numero;
    private Cliente cliente;
    private Vendedor vendedor;
    private double precoOriginal;
    private double desconto;
    private double preco;

    public Compra(double pO, double ds, double pF, Cliente client){        
        cliente = client;
        String s = cliente.getNome();
        String sub = s.substring(0, 3);
        String num = String.valueOf((int)(Math.random()*10000+100));
        numero = num + sub;
        precoOriginal = pO;
        desconto = ds;
        preco = pF; 
    }
```

Método da classe "Cliente":

```
public Compra fazUmaCompra(double p){   
    double pf = 0;
    double ds = 0;
        if (p > 300){
            if (pontos > 2000){
                pf = p - (p * 0.05);
                ds = pf - p;
                pontos = 0;
            }    
            else if (pontos > 1000){
                 pf = p - (p * 0.03);
                 ds = pf - p;
                 pontos = pontos - (int) p * 1;
            }    
            else if (pontos > 500){
                pf = p - (p * 0.02);
                ds = pf - p;
                pontos = pontos - (int) p * 1;
            }
            else
                pf = p;

    }
    pontos = pontos + (int) p * 1;
    Compra c = new Compra(p, ds, pf, this.Cliente);
    return c;
```

Ao compilar, o BlueJ marca "this.Cliente" como erro. "Cannot find symbol - variable Cliente.
Obrigado

Comment: Em vez de `this.Cliente` escreva apenas `this`

Comment: obrigado @ramaral , erro idiota de iniciante hahah

Comment: coloque   

        pontos = pontos + (int) p * 1;
        Compra c = new Compra(p, ds, pf, this.Cliente);
        return c;

dentro das chaves

Comment: @asousajose na verdade as chaves são do if, é que tá mal identado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` se refere a `esse objeto`, como você está dentro de um método da classe Cliente você deve passar apenas o `this` como argumento, pois assim você estará passando o objeto atual, que é do tipo Cliente, como parâmetro para o contrutor de `Compra`. Corrija assim:

```
Compra c = new Compra(p, ds, pf, this);
```

Comment: Hahahahah Genial, obrigado!!

Answer (score -3):

Atenção a mensagem, amigo, "Cannot find symbol - variable Cliente".
O Java é case sensitive, portanto, a variável criada `cliente` não pode ser chamada `Cliente`.
Outra coisa: no seu construtor, ao passar os valores para as variáveis membro você deve usar `this.cliente`, por exemplo, devido ao escopo das variáveis. Usando somente `cliente =` ... você está tentando usar uma variável não criada neste escopo, ou seja, dentro do construtor.

Comment: 1) na classe Cliente não existe nenhuma variável `cliente`, então se puser `this.cliente` o erro permanecerá, o correto é colocar apenas `this`; 2) não existe o menor problema em fazer `cliente = ...` dentro do construtor, pois o construtor consegue enxergar a variável da classe

Comment: Caraca maluco... cliente é um atributo da classe! Pq ñ seria visível no construtor?!!?!?!?